# What is the best multilingual library for apphooks in django-cms?

Tags: localization, django-cms

I am looking for the best solution to solve the problem of multilingual webpage with django-cms. Django-cms has build in multilangs and is working cool. Now I prepare my own app. I am going to connect this app with django-cms by apphook. I need some clever idea for puting langs into my app. The best solution is to have the same tabs with langs in my app, like is in django-cms page. I love this cms's solution but I haven't got idea how to do this. Have you got any ideas?

---

Ok, I see that I have minus one point for my question, I don't understand why. I did a lot of research. I was trying transmeta, is not what I was expected, django-multilingual  error:

```
multilingual/templatetags/multilingual_tags.py in reorder_translation_formset_by_language_id, line 82
```

multilingual-ng is not supported.

In djangopackages.com I found a lot of libs, I am think about this django-modeltranslation but still I am looking the best solution that is the most similar to  django-cms - this tabs looks very cool. If anybody could help me, if you could give me some suggestions I will be glad. Thanks.

Comment: Django-modeltranslation is working according to my needs. Now the only point is to put nice tabs with langs in admin, and to show fields without translation as empty. Now, I must change language globally for all django-admin if I would like to add new translation for some language. I think translation and lang of admin should work separatly or I miss something in my settings?  Still I hope we will start discussion.

Comment: According to my research django-modeltranslation gives very nice tabs in admin. Still is the problem of integration with django-cms: `code`field. django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: PlaceholderField is not supported by modeltranslation.

The best in this situation could be the adaptation of django-cms solution of translations. If anybody know how to do this in the clear way, It will be nice to share with me.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad

Very strong ties to django CMS so it's very likely to work, and continue working.